How to read program files' content in NodeJS
My goal is to make an array of file content from a directory. The directory can resemble a project with source code like Python, JS, etc. So far I have it loop through an array of every file in the directory which works but I don't think this is the best way to go about this, especially since I tested it out with a package-lock.json file with a lot of content.
const fs = require("fs");

for (let i = 0; i < directoryFiles.length; i++){
    fs.readFile(directory + '/' + directoryFiles[i] , 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
       if(err){
          directoryFileContents.push(data);
       }
       directoryFileContents.push(data);
       console.log(directoryFileContents[i]);
    });
}

 


If you have a lot of content, you might want to compress it.

If your goal is to read all the files of an existing directory into memory, there's no other way to do it besides looping through all the files and reading them all individually.  So, it's not clear what else you're asking here.  If you control the content, then all the files could be packaged into a ZIP file and you could read them from the ZIP (though that is a bit more complicated than just reading from the file system).

FYI, your existing code has some issues.  It doesn't handle file reading errors properly.  And, because fs.readFile() is asynchronous, there's way for you to know when you're done reading all the files.
